# How can I get the minted package to render code blocks with copyable indentation?

Tags: python, latex, pygments

To the naked eye, [**minted**](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/minted) (Konrad Rudolph's LaTeX package for code highlighting using the Pygments library)  faithfully renders code blocks that are passed to it, displaying them with whatever indentation was contained in the source code.

If, however, you attempt to copy and paste code from one of those blocks, you'll notice that their visible indentation is achieved using non-copyable
spaces, such that the pasted code loses each line's leading spaces. This is
particularly problematic with Python code blocks, because in Python
indentation has actual meaning as a part of the code.

**So, here's my question**: Is there some way to get **minted** to render code blocks that, when
copy-and-pasted, keep the indentation of the source code they display?

For examples of what I mean, see any of the several indented code blocks in
the **minted** manual ([found
here](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/minted)), or compile
the following minimal-ish reproducible example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\newminted[python]{python}{frame=single}

\begin{document}

\begin{python}
def example1():
    if verbose:
        print 'Running example1'

verbose = True
example1()
\end{python}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148144/viewer-independent-copyable-spaces-at-the-beginning-of-a-line

Comment: @G.Poore Thanks, but as far as I can see, that doesn't help me with **minted**, which I'm wanting for its code highlighting. (I just tried copying all of the relevant code from the accepted answer to the question you linked into my preamble (plus the bit that goes below `\begin{document}`), and it made no difference to the output.) I suspect (?) this is an issue with Pygments, which is why I chose to post here rather than tex.stackexchange.com ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works in Acrobat Reader, at least on my system, but not in SumatraPDF and perhaps some other programs.  There may be other, better solutions.

```
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{minted}
\newminted[python]{python}{frame=single}
\fvset{showspaces}
\renewcommand\FancyVerbSpace{\textcolor{white}{\char32}}
```

This sets `fancyvrb`, which Pygments uses for formatting output, to use visible space characters (`␣`), and then makes the characters "invisible" by making them white.  Ultimately, this does end up being a TeX question, since Pygments is using the `fancyvrb` package for its output, and the trick is to get `fancyvrb` to create (leading) spaces that can be copied.

Comment: Super! How clever. I guess I should have tried David Carlisle's solution at the link, but saw the "white visible spaces" and wrongly assumed they'd be copied as something visible when when copy-and-pasting. I'll hold off on the "accept" for a while, only in case as you say, there's another even better solution.